# short curly braces with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, braces

Is there a way to get curly braces with tikz which look more like this one?
[image: curly brace]

At the moment I'm using the following to get curly braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=0.75cm}]  (0,0) -- (1,0);  
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace]  (0,0) -- (1,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But that results in:

[image: output curly braces]

The point is that I need short curly braces with kind of a high amplitude which still look like braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a primitive meta-decoration, but it is not as general as the standard `brace` such as `raise,mirror` etc. won't work. However, the brace amplitude and other local `brace` options are passed and would be available as I tried to show below. The new raise amount is controlled with `meta-amplitude` key.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\pgfdeclaremetadecoration{raisedbrace}{initial}{%
\state{initial}[width=\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength]{%
  \decoration{brace}%
  \pgfsetdecorationsegmenttransformation{%
      \pgftransformyshift{\pgfmetadecorationsegmentamplitude}%
  }
  \beforedecoration{
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointmetadecoratedpathfirst}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{%
      \pgfpointmetadecoratedpathfirst%
      }{%
      \pgfpointpolar{\pgfdecoratedangle+90}{\pgfmetadecorationsegmentamplitude}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \afterdecoration{%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointmetadecoratedpathlast}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }
}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[style=help lines] (-1,-1) grid[step=1cm] (3,3);
\draw[decorate,decoration={raisedbrace,amplitude=2mm,meta-amplitude=4mm}]  (0,1) -- (2,2);  
\draw[decorate,decoration={raisedbrace,amplitude=4mm,meta-amplitude=1cm}]  (0,-1) -- (2,-0.5);
\draw[decorate,decoration={raisedbrace,amplitude=1cm,meta-amplitude=5mm}]  (2,3) -- (2,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I can emulate the "raise" option by adjusting the nodes (like \draw... ([yshift=1cm]node.east)...), but how to change the thickness? Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: @antonius Just put `\pgfsetlinewidth{\pgflinewidth}` before `\pgfusepath{stroke}` then you can put `thick` etc. inside `\draw` options and it should obey.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(0.5,0.5) -- (5.0,0.5) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm]
{};
\node at (2.65,1.0) {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The length of the brace can be altered with the values in the `\draw` command `(0.5,0.5) -- (5.0,0.5)`. Similarly the text position need to be altered.
[image]

### Update

Varying the amplitude, we get something like this:
[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=14pt},xshift=-4pt,yshift=0pt]
(0.5,0.5) -- (5.0,0.5) node [black,midway,xshift=-0.6cm]
{};
\node at (2.65,1.2) {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but for short curly braces it will result in the same mutation as above (e.g. "(0.5,0.5) -- (1.5,0.5)" )